# Resizing a base64 image from react-native app in laravel api?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, react-native

I'm trying to develop an app that can send a user image input in base64 from their device camera and let my api handle, resize and save the image in jpg format, I'm using `react-native image-picker` as the camera handler. Here's my code so far

```
// in imageHandlerController.php
public function resizeImage($image) {
    $resizeImage = Image::make($images)->resize(512, 512, function($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->orientate();

    return $resizeImage->response();
}

public function imageHandler(Request $request){
DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $constants = Config::get('constants');
        $path = $constants['UPLOAD_PATH'].'/images';
        $random_name = str_random(20);
        $selfie = $request->selfieImage;
        $selfie = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $selfie);
        $selfie = str_replace(' ', '+', $selfie);
        $selfie_name = 'selfie-'.$random_name.'.png';
        File::put($path.'/partners/'.$selfie_name, $this->resizeImage($selfie));
 }
```

Here's the post request on index.js

```
launchCameraSelfie = () => {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(response => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else {
        let source = response;
        this.setState({
          selfieImage: source.data
        });
      }
    });
 };
```

It show `Unable to init from binary data` as an error
How can i do this? any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Where is `Image::` coming from? Is it a third party package?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the `Intervention Image` package. The [documentation](http://image.intervention.io/api/make) shows that it is indeed possible to convert a base64 string to an `Image`.

What is unclear to me is why you remove the initial string `data:image/png;base64,` from the encoded image. I can imagine this part to be necessary for Intervention to work.

I shortened and rewrote your code a bit. This works for me:

```
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
```

```
$selfie = $request->selfieImage;

$img = Image::make($selfie);
$img->resize(512, 512, function($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
})->orientate();
$img->save(storage_path('images') . '/test.png');
```

---

For easy testing, the following base64 image can be used (it represents a single black pixel):

```
$selfie = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNk+A8AAQUBAScY42YAAAAASUVORK5CYII=';
```

---

If you want to do some in-depth debugging, have a look at Intervention's `AbstractDecoder` class and its `init()` function. It is the place where the image type is identified, and for some reason your image is identified as binary.